# Update table via xml input

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a stored proc that inserts new records in my 2008 SQL server table via xml input:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_AddBinsToBox
@BoxId          BIGINT,
@BinIds         XML
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO WebServiceBoxDetails 
(
  BinId,
  BoxId 
)
SELECT 
  ParamValues.ID.value('.','VARCHAR(20)'),
  @BoxId  
FROM 
  @binIds.nodes('/Bins/id') AS ParamValues(ID)
```

This works great for inserting new rows, the thing i'm confused about is updating (via UPDATE statement) this same table with new xml input?

Table:

```
Id(PK)    BoxNumber  BinId
(bigint)  (bigint)   (int)
_______________________
1           12         334
2           12         445
3           12         776
4           16         223
5           16         669
```

Command to be used:

```
EXEC upd_Box @binIds='<Bins><id>7848</id><id>76554</id><id>71875</id></Bins>', @BoxId=12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. Here is the answer for your second part(this should work for both update and insert)

```
DECLARE @binIds AS XML = '<Bins><id>44</id><id>55</id><id>66</id><id>77</id></Bins>'
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @newid INT
DECLARE @count INT = 1
DECLARE @BinIdTable TABLE(RowNumber INT, BinId INT) 
DECLARE @BoxNumber INT = 12
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 0

INSERT @BinIdTable(RowNumber, BinId)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), ParamValues.ID.value('.','INT')
FROM
 @binIds.nodes('/Bins/id') AS ParamValues(ID)

SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM @BinIdTable

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT id FROM WebServiceBoxDetails WHERE BoxNumber = @BoxNumber ORDER BY id

 OPEN MyCursor

 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
 INTO @id

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN

    SELECT @newid =  B.BinId
    FROM @BinIdTable B
        WHERE RowNumber = @count

    UPDATE WebServiceBoxDetails
        SET BinId = @newid
        WHERE Id = @id

    SET @count = @count + 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor 
    INTO @id
 END
 CLOSE MyCursor
 DEALLOCATE MyCursor

 IF @RowCount >= @count
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO WebServiceBoxDetails
    SELECT @BoxNumber, BinId 
        FROM @BinIdTable
        WHERE RowNumber >= @count

 END
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for all your time. It works exactly the way I need. Apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NODES method again.

```
UPDATE WebServiceBoxDetails
SET BinID = ParamValues.ID.value('@BinID','VARCHAR(20)')
FROM
 @bindIDs.nodes('/Bins/id') AS ParamValues(ID)
 JOIN WebServiceBoxDetails w ON w.ID = ParamValues.ID.value('@id','VARCHAR(20)')
 WHERE w.BoxNumber = @BoxID
```

Comment: Thank you! My code was similar but i was getting 'Parameter value errors' I'll try that now.

Comment: For some reason this only uses the first XML entry for each record??? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: sorry I didn't get that. This behaves like a normal update statement. It takes the first value and update the column with that value. Can you please explain what exactly you want? thanks

Comment: i call it with EXEC upd_Box @binIds='<Bins><id>1</id><id>2</id><id>3</id></Bins>', @BoxId=12
  and it only inserts every record with 1 (or whatever the first xml entry is). I need to update the entire record with the contents of the xml string. still cant figure it out. thanks

Comment: So you want 1,2 and 3 under row 12? Could you please put it in a table? like what you want and what you have. Thanks.

Comment: i mocked up a table above. i want to update box 12 with a new list of binId's that are in an XML string passed to the SQL proc. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize for the run around, I haven’t provided enough data to you. The code you provided doesn’t work… I tried tweaking it with no luck. I provided the column data types above with the expected call to the proc. Thanks for your time.

Comment: it works for me. I did create a sample and did this. If you can show me the xml you pass that would help.

Comment: i pass exactly what i provided above... i didnt know if the datatype missmatch was an issue?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were passing ID (primary key) as well. Simple (but may be not the best) solution would be to loop through the WebServiceBoxDetails table and update each record. Let me know if you want to see a sample code.

Comment: I'd like to keep consistency with my other procs that are inserting xml strings, could you provide an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @binIds AS XML = '<Bins><id>7848</id><id>76554</id><id>71875</id></Bins>'
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @newid INT
DECLARE @count INT = 1
DECLARE @BinIdTable TABLE(RowNumber INT, BinId INT) 

INSERT @BinIdTable(RowNumber, BinId)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), ParamValues.ID.value('.','INT')
FROM
 @binIds.nodes('/Bins/id') AS ParamValues(ID)


DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
 SELECT id FROM WebServiceBoxDetails WHERE BoxNumber = 12 ORDER BY id

 OPEN MyCursor

 FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
 INTO @id

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN

    SELECT @newid =  B.BinId
    FROM @BinIdTable B
        WHERE RowNumber = @count

    UPDATE WebServiceBoxDetails
        SET BinId = @newid
        WHERE Id = @id

    SET @count = @count + 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor 
    INTO @id
 END
 CLOSE MyCursor
 DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: A valiant attempt, but no matter what it only updates the WebServiceBoxDetails table with the first item in the xml string??? I don’t understand why it’s not working…

Comment: strange! if you have tried the exact code I have given above it should definitely work. Cross check your code again if you like with the one above. Also you may debug the code and see where it goes wrong. Like check if you get all the values in the xml into the temp table (@BinIdTable), etc

Comment: Also if you are passing the xml from an application check whether it passes the correct string to the stored proc.

Comment: Did you get all the values in the xml (as individual rows) to the temp table as above? 
Next rather than doing the update, just select the BinID inside the cursor and see what you get.

Comment: i copied your example line for line and it didn't work with my existing db... just updated the record to include the first entry in the xml string

Comment: I was expecting answers to my previous two questions. You have to drill down a bit to find where the problem is.

Comment: I did step through this, but due to my lack of experience with SQL (and SQL cursors) it’s difficult to diagnose the issue. I’m assuming the problem is coming from [where RowNumber = @Count]… In my WebServiceBoxDetails column, Id is an auto generated primary key, BoxNumber is the FK from a parent table WebServiceBoxes, which contains the actual user information related to the box.

Comment: I did a little tweak to the cursor. see if that works. let me know.

Comment: Getting closer!! now lets say there is 2 existing entries for box 8 and i'm updating box 8 with 3 new entries (like in the above xml), this current code updates the 2 that exist, but doesn't create the 3rd record???...

Comment: Your initial question was regarding the update statement.so i hope it is not getting closer rather it is working? I will post the answer as a new answer for your 2nd question